# Rendering an image with Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, nginx

Have the following code in action:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$image = ...
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

This generates a broken image on server but works fine on localhost.

Even that code in action generates a broken image:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents('.../test.png');
```

Also I've tried to put this 2 lines:

1. in index.php: it works fine
2. in Zend_Controller_Action: it response broken image

Comment: What content server returns? You can look in developer tools -> network -> request. It is possible that server returns error + image, so browser can't display it.

Comment: @MaxP. no errors in response: Status Code:200 OK, Content-Type:image/png

Comment: No, I mean content. Save response to disk and open it with any editor. Look if it contain only binary data.

Comment: @MaxP. Editor says that the image is broken too

Comment: Try to open it with text editor

Comment: ![Screen](https://yadi.sk/i/mJ0Uw3XumqCjo)

Comment: Strange, no errors, content is present. Try to compare source image and downloaded. May be content is changing by some ZF plugins.

Comment: Put exit() after echo. Because Zend post dispatch makes echo and ruins the header

Comment: @joao impossible. it works on the local machine but it doesn't on another server

Answer (score 2):

```
public function imgAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $img = file_get_contents("Your Image");
    $type = 'image/png';

    $response = $this->getFrontController()->getResponse();

    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', $type, true);
    $response->setHeader('Content-Length', count($img), true);
    $response->setBody($img);

    $response->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

The example is taken from http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Outputting-an-image-td655625.html#d1224890879000-12